# Filter resultset of records in xml tree view - Odoo 10

Tags: xml, filter, treeview, resultset, odoo

I have a model Employee with the fields `e_name, e_num, e_addr and e_dept`. I want to display the employee details of those who are in department `HR, Audit and Production` only in the xml tree view. How can i do this filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```
<search string="Search Employee">
   <field name="e_name" string="Emp Name" filter_domain="[('e_name', 'in' ,['hr','audit','production'])]"/>
</search>
```

Comment: Maybe you can use 'e_dept' instead of 'e_name' in the filter_domain